# What is safer, mysql anti-sqli + xss solution

Tags: php, mysql, xss

is this code safe?

```
$name = htmlspecialchars($mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["name"]), ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
```

or should i use this

```
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"], ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8"));
```

or it doesn't matter? Thx

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

Protect your database from SQL injection *when making queries*. Where possible, do it [with parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068) instead of manual escaping.

Protect your HTML from XSS *when you generate your HTML*. i.e. apply `htmlspecialchars` to the data you get *out* of the database, not the data you put into it.

Comment: Oh, ok, so the page could get hacked when i use $mysqli->real_escape_string( ? Because i tried putting ' etc to the field that gets sent to database and it was working all right.